# Sort for a large number of string record by time in Java

Tags: java, performance, sorting, memory, timestamp

I have a CSV with several million lines of records, I like to sort it by time. Currently, I just put it in a treemap with `ZonedDateTime` as key. Is there a better way to do that? Guess at least it is better to use `toEpochSecond()` and use EpochSecond as the key? If there further improvement?

The time is in a field in the CSV, below is one example:

```
ABC.DE,,Market Price,2018-07-19T08:21:32.633494851+01,Quote,,,,,19.01,425,,,21.09,250,,,298911,21:32.6,,,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: Sort if by time in what way? The time you read the line in or, some `DateTime` field you're reading from each row?

Comment: Could you give us a sample of that csv?

Comment: There probably is no better way.  You could try using Longs instead of ZonedDateTimes as keys, but if there isn’t a significant speed improvement, I would continue to use ZonedDateTimes, as the code will be clearer.

Comment: can you put a sample of CSV file?

Comment: If you don’t experience any issues, what you have is just fine. If you do have issues with performance or something else, let us know, and improvements will be possible.

Comment: HI, the time is in a field in the CSV, below is one example: 

    ABC.DE,,Market Price,2018-07-19T08:21:32.633494851+01,Quote,,,,,19.01,425,,,21.09,250,,,298911,21:32.6,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: It take quite a lot memory and kind of slow, BTW, if in case if the time is duplicated, I need to adjust the timing a bit otherwise the record will be lost. Not sure if there are other approach which can use less memory, or faster, or don't need to make sure time is distinct

Comment: Your date-time of `2018-07-19T08:21:32.633494851+01` hasn’t got any time zone, so `ZonedDateTime` is overkill. `OffsetDateTime` is a good choice. You may conduct tests to determine if `Instant` performs better. Epoch second will lose information (the fraction of second).

Answer (score 1):

For sorting, use sort. There's `Arrays::sort` and `Collections::sort` (and `sorted` for streams).

> BTW, if in case if the time is duplicated, I need to adjust the timing a bit otherwise the record will be lost. Not sure if there are other approach which can use less memory, or faster, or don't need to make sure time is distinct.

For sure, plain `sort` doesn't need the time to be distinct. It most probably needs less memory and is a bit faster.

For really huge data, you could do some kind of file merge sort, so that you don't need to keep it all in memory. However, when you have that much memory, then there's nothing to gain, is it?

> Guess at least it is better to use toEpochSecond() and use EpochSecond as the key?

Maybe. Or save yourself all the parsing and sort the strings instead. Assuming you're using the same timezone everywhere, then `2018-07-19T08:21:32.633494851+01`  compares the same no matter if you treat it as datetime or string.

Comment: Design a class with two fields, the time and the CSV line. Sort instances of this class by time. Since the time doesn’t some first on the line, sorting the lines as text will not give you the desired result. Also sorting the time strings not only would require the same offset, but also the same number of decimals on the seconds.